# Variable width column chart with cumsum function in R

Tags: r, cumsum

I am trying to make a variable width column chart with 4 non overlapping columns each representing a step.

the width of each column: width = c(25,50,75,100)
height = c(10,20,40,30)

This is the code I have found which works great as long as the width values are positive:

End point of each column: df$w <- cumsum(df$width)  resulting in (25,75,150, 250)

Start point of each column: df$wm <- df$w - df$width  resulting in (0,25,75,150)

If I have a negative number for the width of the first column (-25,50,75,100) then the above cumsum code for the end point of the columns (w) results in (-25,25,100,200 ) and the starting point gives (0, -25,25,100). This means my columns overlap.  And i don't want any overlap so I would like to amend the above code to result in the following:  endpoint w=(-25,50, 125, 225) and starting point (0,0,50,125).

Could somebody please help me?

Comment: Amazing!  Thank you sooo much for your help!

Comment: may i ask you then: In order to create a graph using S and the E that you have created with this function can I use the following: library(ggplot2) p <- ggplot(df, aes(ymin = 0)) p1 <- p + geom_rect(aes(xmin = s, xmax = e , ymax = Variability, fill = Steps)) p1 What is the correct way of calling S and E here? because with my way they are not recognized. I get the error saying object s not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you what I think you're looking for -

```
widths_to_starts_ends <- function(widths){
  
  widths <- widths[widths != 0]
  pos_widths <- widths[widths > 0]
  neg_widths <- widths[widths < 0]
  
  pos_ends <- cumsum(pos_widths)
  pos_starts <- cumsum(pos_widths) - pos_widths
  
  neg_widths <- abs(neg_widths)
  neg_starts <- cumsum(neg_widths)
  neg_ends <- cumsum(neg_widths) - neg_widths
  
  neg_starts <- (-1)*neg_starts
  neg_ends <- (-1)*neg_ends
  
  return( list(s = c(neg_ends, pos_starts), e = c(neg_starts, pos_ends)) )
  
}

widths_to_starts_ends(c(25,50,75,100))
```

```
$s
[1]   0  25  75 150

$e
[1]  25  75 150 250
```

And the result with "negative width" -

```
widths_to_starts_ends(c(-25,50,75,100))
```

```
$s
[1]   0   0  50 125

$e
[1] -25  50 125 225
```

Comment: may i ask you then:  In order to create a graph using S and the E that you have created with this function can I use the following: library(ggplot2)
p  <- ggplot(df, aes(ymin = 0))
p1 <- p + geom_rect(aes(xmin = s, xmax = e , ymax = Variability, fill = Steps))
p1   What is the correct way of calling S and E here? because with my way they are not recognized.  I get the error saying object s not found

Comment: hard to say without having the data. this should work - df <- as_tibble(widths_to_starts_ends(c(25,50,75,100))) %>% tibble::add_column(variability = 1:4)
 
ggplot(df, aes(ymin = 0)) + geom_rect(aes(xmin = s, xmax = e , ymax = variability))`

Comment: Hello again and thank you!  here is an echantillon of  my data: I have three steps (columns) and am trying to visualize the variability (height) and the mean ( variable width) of each.   df <- data.frame (Steps = c("Step1", "Step2", "Step3"), Variability = c(sd(dataset$PS01,na.rm = TRUE), sd(dataset$PS02, na.rm = TRUE), sd(dataset$PS03, na.rm = TRUE)), Width = c(mean(dataset$PS01,na.rm = TRUE), mean(dataset$PS02, na.rm = TRUE), mean(dataset$PS03, na.rm = TRUE))).  I am doing this in the R script of Power BI.  The  PS01, PS03 are columns that i have imported in PowerBI.